SQL : having after group by returns what?
enter image description here
I wanted to get 1,3,4 back as their tiv_2015 values are appearing more than once, but I got 1 only.
Help in need to understand how select works after having clause.
select pid 
from insurance 
group by tiv_2015
having count(*) > 1

I also tried without group by, still have 1 back.
select pid 
from insurance 
having count(tiv_2015) > 1

Then I tried below and get 10 back. So shall I select the column appearing in group by or having clause and use a outer query to get the pid I wanted?
select tiv_2015 
from insurance 
having count(tiv_2015) > 1


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Please tag your RDBMS

You better read about HAVING without GROUP BY rather than just remove GROUP BY for no reason.

First, grab the list of tiv values you want, then grab the pids that match:
SELECT pid FROM insurance
WHERE tiv_2015 in 
    (SELECT tiv_2015 FROM insurance GROUP BY tiv_2015 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);

Output:
1
3
4

